# Primefaces effect on growl only triggered second time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, primefaces

I have this piece of code:

```
    <p:growl id="growler" autoUpdate="true">
        <h:outputScript>
                $("#growler_container").effect("slide", { direction: "right" }, 400);
            </h:outputScript>
    </p:growl>
```

Anytime the growl is activated through a message, the first time it is shown the default way. The second time the 'slide' effect is working as should. How to ensure this also works the first time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved the h:outputScript code to the p:button who was triggering the message and it works.

```
<p:growl id="growler" autoUpdate="true" life="15000"/>

<p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{referenceManagementPage.save}" update="@form">
    <h:outputScript>$("#growler_container").effect("slide", { direction: "right" }, 400);</h:outputScript>
</p:commandButton>
```